# Elixir-Phoenix: disable Hammer's rate limiting in testing

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, hammer

I need to disable rate limiting (or substantially increase the limit) in a Phoenix app for the test mode (because the tests exceed the limit). I use [Hammer](https://github.com/ExHammer/hammer) library for the rate limiting.

I'm looking for something other than checking for the test mode when serving a request.

(I couldn't find an answer either in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/hammer/frontpage.html) or in the [example app's source](https://github.com/ExHammer/hammer-testbed).)

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with checking for the test mode? Configure the desired value inside your /config files and use a different value in `test.exs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in Jonas Dellinger's comment to the question, I ended up setting the number of requests and a timescale in custom variables in `/config/config.exs` and `/config/test.exs` (ones in the latter "overwrite" values in the former in the test mode). I get these values for Hammer's [`check_rate/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/hammer/Hammer.html#check_rate/3) via [`Application.get_env/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3).